# What causes this large horizontal space between two sentences?

Tags: spacing, graphics

I have a large document based on the book documentclass with text and images, and sometimes I encounter a new sentence that has a huge space after a period.
It looks like this:
[image]

I have attempted to make a MWE, but failed to get the problem.

This problem generally occurs when I have code that has this general structure:

```
A sentence that explains something shown in the images.
%
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[clip=true, trim=0 0 0 0, width=0.9\linewidth, angle=0]{image}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[clip=true, trim=0 0 0 0, width=0.9\linewidth, angle=0]{image}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{figure}[htpb] 
    \includegraphics[clip=true, trim=0 0 0 0, width=0.8\linewidth, angle=0]{image} 
\end{figure}
%
Another sentence that continues on the explanation.
```

It compiles then to something like this:

```
A sentence that explains something shown in the images.    Another sentence that continues on the explanation.
<image><image>
   <image>
```

What could be causing this large jump? Is there some package/option that is known to give this discrepancy? As said I've tried to compile a MWE but failed to achieve this "error".
If I knew what might cause this I could re-attempt to produce an MWE.

Comment: Add `figure` environments *between* paragraphs, not inside them.

Comment: Change `\end{figure}` to `\end{figure}%` twice. There are spaces at the end of the lines.

Comment: Related: [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate. It's the same subject/problem, but the linked question approaches it from the other side ("what does this solution do?") and my question is more along the lines of "I have this problem, how do I solve this".

Comment: @Werner This is rather different from the canonical `% at eol` question. For a single figure you don't need the `%` and LaTeX explicitly checks for and compensates for any white space. It is just that its checks can not cope with a run of alternating insert and space nodes.

Comment: @egreg I had that before, but I noticed it took more space (in terms of pages) hence I switched to the method of including figure environments in paragraphs. This saved me 4 pages on a document of 100. When the text needs a paragraph because of the content I of course begin a new paragraph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's OK to put figures in paragraphs but if you put them one after the other you must have no space between them. You have a word space between each from the end of line, and the figures float away leaving the space.

```
\end{figure}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%
\begin{figure}[htpb]
```

LaTeX takes precautions so that if there is space before and after a figure only one space appears in the final paragraph, however it doesn't (and can't easily) check that a space between two figures is "after" one figure and "before" the next so both figures see a space and add a single space to the final para so you get two spaces.

Comment: Is it good practice to write `\end{environment}%` in general? Or is this something which I should consider per case?

Comment: @BartArondson I moved the answer to that comment into my updated answer.